# How to fix "I don't see any images after ng buildng build --prod --output-path="/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/dist/ "

Tags: angular, wordpress

I create template Angular 7 on Wordpress. Locally(http://localhost:4200) everthing it's fine but when I'll make ng build --prod --output-path="/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/dist/" It doesn't work properly. I can't see images - img. I don't writte about images generated by css. These work properly. 
I don't know why. My english isn't so good. Please calm down.

Comment: You have to replace {theme_name} with the name of your theme, you know that, right?

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect Your Image requests in Network tab. check from where the file is being requested.
please provide detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the requests. I get 500 (Internal Server Error). In 
Wordress  corret path is to image "/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/assets/images/img/logo.png". When I add that path, I get 500 (Internal Server Error). 
My snippet in angular.json.

```html
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Link in src have to look like "/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/dist/{image_name}.png".